# XCUITest not recognizing alert

Tags: swift, xcuitest

I'm new to XCUITest and have come across a problem where it's not recognizing an alert.

I used the recorder to get the commands, but when I try to play it back, it fails with an error saying:

No matches found for Find: Descendants matching type Alert from input...

```
let app = XCUIApplication()
    app.navigationBars["Spree.HomeWebView"].children(matching: .button).element(boundBy: 1).tap()
    app.alerts["Select a Saved Password to Use With “Spree-DEBUG”"].buttons["Not Now"].tap()
```

I thought it might be a problem with the double quotes in the string, but when I tried the following:

```
app.alerts["Select a Saved Password to Use With \“Spree-DEBUG\”"].buttons["Not Now"].tap()
```

It said Invalid escape sequence in the literal.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to query a button that is inside an alert, you can omit whole alerts subscript part of your query. Just like:

```
app.alerts.buttons["Not Now"].tap()
```

This is because you probably don't have more than one alert shown at the same time, so querying all `alerts` should give the one you need since you only have one, right :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but when I tried to run that I got the following error:

    UI Test Activity: 
    Assertion Failure: CheckoutKeywords.swift:36: No matches found for Find: 
    Descendants matching type Alert from input {(
        Application, 0x6000003805b0, pid: 14258, label: 'Spree-DEBUG'
    )}

Comment: OK, is that a system button? Like Notifications or Location permission alert. Or is it an alert from any other app that pops out in front of your app? Also, does it take time for that alert to appear (more than 1-2 seconds)?

Comment: It's a system button, I can locate it in the hierarchy, but it doesn't manage to pick it up when the test runs.
It takes a couple of seconds to load, but I've put in a wait (just using sleep (15) for now) to make sure it's displayed before the test looks for it.

Comment: You should be able to locate system alert by: `let springboardApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")`, `springboardApp.alerts`.

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a real solution, basically what happens iOS 11-12 works fine with a handler, but iOS13 doesn't if you uninstall app during automation. So as guys provided you need to use springboard activity to handle alerts which are not part of the app, and conclusion:

1. Handle addUIInterruptionMonitor
2. Handle app.alerts
3. springboard alerts